# Place Image above another image dynamically in ReactNative App

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have an iOS app in which, we take user pics, and then allowed them to put some random custom images above the pics.

While placing these custom pics above real image, they can rotate, scale these custom image. ( See this [StickerViewIOS](https://github.com/zedoul/ZDStickerView) )

Now I am looking for exact same solution while making ReactNative.

Tried lot of Googling but no results found.

Just want to ask community if any of the ReactNative component available for the same.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no rotation support, but I did something similar for an app I made for Chain React.

Here's the image component that supports gestures: https://github.com/cball/ChainReactPhotobomb/blob/master/App/Components/TransformableImage.js

To overlay them on top, just use the [ImageBackground Component](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html#background-image-via-nesting)

Comment: Thank you very much. Its somewhat similar to what I was looking for. Thanks a ton!!!